# How to model the association of CDs with Genres?

Tags: sql, rdbms

I'm creating a database design for a web site that sells music CDs, and I've hit a brick wall because I can't get my head around whether the relationship between an CD and it's Genre's is one-to-many or many-to-many

Each CD can have multiple genres. For example "Ministry of Sound Dubstep Anthems" could have genres such as Dubstep, Dance and Electro.

The more I think about it though, each genre can also be linked to a number of CD's.

The way I have my Database at the moment is:

```
cd_table
   PK ID
   FK Genre
   Description
   ...

genre_table
   PK ID
   Genre
```

If it was a many-to-many am I right in thinking I will need a join table such as:

```
cd_genre
   CD_ID
   Genre_ID
```

And then have them both acting as a Primary Key? How would I link the cd_genre to the cd_table? Or do I just remove the FK in cd_table, and then do a join when querying the CD's?

Comment: Yup. That's exactly how you should do it.

Comment: Ah damn. Looks like I was correct. I've not done this since my University days some time ago.

Answer (score 0):

You're correct - the relationship between CD and Genre *is* many-to-many, for exactly the reasons you provide.

And yes, a cross-reference/join table like you describe is what you need.

---

Interestingly, depending on other constraints, you might want to be able to put genre in other places, too.  For instance, song: an artist like [Weird Al](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%22Weird_Al%22_Yankovic) may put several different genres of songs on one of his albums, and the album itself doesn't necessarily have any single 'main' genre (but often have some 'theme').

Answer (score 0):

I think you answered your own question.  CD's and Genres are many-to-many, and you accomplish it with that two column table with the two foreign keys, usually referred to as a "join table."  It's generally not necessary to think of that table as having a primary key, but rationally the two columns together are a composite primary key.

Comment: Ah, so there's nothing I need to do when creating the tables to make them both act as the PK?

Comment: It would probably depend on the specifics of your framework.  Practically speaking you never NEED to define primary keys to use a database.  They're just there to make it harder to screw things up, and sometimes to help with optimization of queries and things like that.

Answer (score 0):

To determine multiplicity, ask the same question starting with the different relations:

1. Can a CD belong to many Genres?
2. Can a Genre contain more than one CD?

Of course, this is *may* be the *wrong* database model. Instead, Song<->Genre and Song<->CD, is the higher Normalized Form. It is a higher NF because CD<->Genre can be composed from CD<->Song<->Genre but CD<->Genre cannot answer the same queries about Songs on the CD (unless a CD can be at most one Genre).

On the other hand, one might *only* care about CDs and not Songs .. in which case modeling Songs irrelevant or even harmful excessive data. Likewise, perfect classification might overcomplicate practical classification - be aware of the tradeoffs between granularity of information and the use to the problem domain.

Comment: Ah, so rather than linking a CD to a genre you are saying link the songs that are contained on the CD with a genre? Along those lines? And then the CD will be composed of all the genres attached to the songs?

Comment: @JamesJeffery Yes, Songs belong to a Genre (perhaps more than one, although how this is modeled depends on the domain). CDs contain Songs. Thus CDs contain Songs of one (or more) Genres and CDs are thus themselves contain one (or more) Genres (by association of Songs). Again, this modeling depends on the domain - and most CD's *aren't* mixed. I've presented a higher NF approach, but it *isn't necessarily* the *correct-er* approach from the Business perspective. Consider walking into a music store - a particular CD is found in R&B or Blues, but not in both places.